# implementing multi language codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Newbie question..After going through the Tank auth authentication library for codeigniter, the way the multi language support is implemented to display error messages is to create a separate folder for each language in the application/language folder. The library supports 11 language and in each language file there are around 30 error messages.

My question is that if I am going to create a library of my own or if i implement the library in my application and i want to change a particular error message, how will i go about doing that? Should i create a default language file (lets say in English) and then manually convert the text to all the other languages or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience you can't automate translations of custom error messages with acceptable results (the available translation services aren't that good and precise yet).

So to answer your question, yes, it's probably best practice to create a language file for each library you  create in Codeigniter, and then manually translate it in each language you want to support in your application (a file for each language stored in `application/language/{language}` folders).

The benefits of creating separate language files for each library is that you kan keep your libraries much more portable compared to if you set all language lines in one general language file to cover your complete application.

Comment: @depz123, I agree with MicKri. You need to create all language files for your translation.